# How to display schedule in struts2 framework?

Tags: class, jdbc, struts2, schedule

I'm looking for help in my project in Struts2. I need to find a solution for displaying weekly schedule of classes. Project uses JDBC as well, values of each classes has to be saved in database. I was thinking of displaying classes in table like beneath, but i don't know how i can dynamically add values by clicking on hour from table.For any type of help, thank you.

```
              Monday       Tuesday      Wednesday  Thursday Friday
```

7.30-8.45
8.15-9.00
9.15-10.00
10.00-10.45
11.00-11.45
11.45-12.30
12.45-13.30
13.30-14.15
14.30-15.15
15.15-16.00
16.15-17.00
17.00-17.45
18.00-18.45
18.45-19.30
19.45-20.30
20.30-21.15

Answer (score 0):

well, I had a project before which used Struts2 + Ibatis (now MyBatis) and it was handled as following, for sure, this is not the most efficient way to do it, but it can give you an approach, I was in 2nd level of the career when I implemented this:

For loading:

1. Create a table "Schedule" with "id", "startDate", "endDate" and "description" (optional)
2. Create a table "Courses" with "id", "name" and "scheduleId"
3. You save your "schedule" like: `insert into schedule values (1, '07:40', '08:50', null);`
4. Save a course this way: `insert into course values('A1','Calculus 1', 1);`

Then you just need to match them in the schedule using your custom "Action" like "LoadScheduleAction" by performing a query to db using jdbc.

If you want to mark the cell with the hour, for example (Monday, 9:40 - 10:50), then you can use "divs" and with javascript color them with blue or green, make sure you give each div and "id" so then you can get the cell you marked. Then, every time you click to select a cell or click to de-select a cell, I mean if you click the first time, then it gets colored, if you select for second time the same cell it returns to its original status and so on. Well, everytime you select a cell, you can save the coords in an array in session (or arraylist, or set) for example, session can contain: (Monday, 9:40 - 10:50), (Tuesday, 9:40 - 10:50) save it like a custom object inside an ArrayList in session:

`ScheduleItem item = new ScheduleItem(day, hourRange);`

Then, everytime you select a sell you get:

```
item1('monday', '9 - 10');
item2('monday, '11 -13');
item3('tuesday, '15-17');
```

and so on... all of them, saved into an arraylist temporary in your session.

```
ArrayList<ScheduleItem> scheduleItems = new ArrayList<ScheduleItem>();
scheduleItems.add(item1)
```

...
And finally when you already click on the button "submit" or something like that, just retrieve that list from session and persist it using jdbc in a new table like "studentSchedule" or "teacherSchedule" depending on what you need to do.

This is a very simple approach based on what I understood with your question. Hope it helps you someway.

Regards.